# Creating an overlay in Android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm currently making an Android app and I'm seeking inspiration in the picture as seen below. I'm trying to create the overlay in the top right corner of the first device in the picture and I have no idea how it is done. 
[image]

Comment: _I'm trying to create the overlay..._ Where is your code?

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: First of all you can check if there are some [libraries or frameworks](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui) done for this Overlay else you can use the [Linearlayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear) it's very easy... Check all libraries that I attached are very usefull

Comment: R. Garcia -I have been looking in the libraries and couldn't find what I was looking for, so I am wondering if you have time to guide me through the Linearlayout way. I'm very new to android development so it would be a big help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alpha` property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#FFFF33"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="Sample Text View Sample Text View Sample Text View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The output will be like

[image]

*********** **`EDITED AS PER OP'S REQUIREMENT`** ***********

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FFFF33"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="Sample Text View Sample Text View Sample Text View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey I have tried your code and it works very well, but when I use the alpha property, it also makes the text behind the overlay faded down. How can I fix this? appreciate the help.

Comment: the `relativelayout` stacks up its child layouts on top of each other, so just place your textview as the last child of your relative layout so that it will appear above the alpha layout, see edited layout

Comment: When I do as you say my text doesn't stand in the overlay anymore and makes it very hard to style any solution to this? As you can see in the picture I need to create some text and progress bar inside the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

add two layout one for background and another for top of it.
then add top layout background color white transparent.

example XML layout given below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#c11316">
    <TextView
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
    android:background="#33e4e4e4">
    <TextView
        android:text="Your Things"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: output look like this]